# How to set html lang and base using static-i18n for translations

Tags: javascript, html

I create landing page in one .html file using pure html-css-js (to be able to run it on simple file serwer like apache). For SEO I decide to generate separate .html files for each supported language - to do it I use [static-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-i18n) which take template html file with translations keys and change it to separate html files (one for each language). My code with translaton keys is inside `./src` directory, the translations shoud be generated inside `./dist` folder using

```
static-i18n --fixPaths false --selector [i18n] --useAttr false -o ./dist -l en -i en -i pl ./src
```

The `./dist` structure is following (I copy there `assets` and `.htaccess` in separate way in my build script):

[image]

the main language (english) is in `./dist/index.html` file, and other languages are in subdirecotry e.g. `./dist/pl/index.html`. Example translation inside `./src/index.html` (the `i18n` attribute means that inside tag content is translation key)

```html
<div class="main__title" i18n >main.title</div>
```

I have two problems - how to set in dynamic way:

- the lang inside tag `<html lang="??">`  (but without changing the way of giving translations keys as in html example above)
- proper href value inside `<base href="...">` tag (for properly reading assets) - in main language should be `<base href="./">` but in other languages (which are in subdirectories) shoud be `<base href="../">`

Answer (score 1):

Here are my solutons - but may be there exists better

- add key `"lang"` to your translation `*.json` files and use it in  tag as follows

```html
<html data-attr-t lang-t="lang">
```

- remove  tag from html and use following js code at the top of  tag to generate proper `<base>`

```js
<script defer>
  // CAUTION! This script must be in <head> tag 
  // (<base> must be set before <body> loading)
  const mainLanguage = 'en'; 

  // set base in dynamic way
  const newBase = document.createElement('base');
  const lang = document.documentElement.lang;
  newBase.setAttribute('href', lang == 'en' ? './' : '../');
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newBase);
</script>
```

or in same way like in `lang` use `<base data-attr-t href-t="base"></base>` (and add key `"base":"./` to `en.json` and `"base":"../"` `pl.json`)